# Why is Machine Learning taught in Computer Science Courses but not in Mathematics?

Tags: machine-learning, general

I always wonder why machine learning is native to computer science rather than its more close fields like statistics and mathematics? In machine learning we CS engineers learn stats and maths and implement it by coding. Wouldn't it be much more easier for say a mathematician and a statistician to learn coding and implementing this stuff? Be it Regression, Deep Learning, SVM, all of the things boils down to maths and stats, so why teach computer science students Machine Learning, and why not teach it to mathematicians and statisticians?

Comment: What happens? Taking a class that you are finding hard and find it comforting to blame it on the class? Mathematicians, statisticians, even physicists, as long they are interested or need to use it, study it. The premise of your question, of not being taught to other specialties, is false.

Comment: Computer science departments were separated from math departments at universities within many of our lifetimes, so the separation between the two isn't as profound as you seem to think.  On the other hand, all of science rests on the bedrock of mathematics and it is normal for other disciplines to wrest off mathematical frameworks and use them as tools toward their own non-mathematical ends.

Comment: Sir, CS is first and foremost a genuine Math field. If you can't even face basic statistics for ML just change course...

Comment: A lot of theoretical computer science is "just math".